# Unclosed quotation

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to pull the selected values from my checkboxlist but I keep running into an error in sql.

error

```
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

SP

```
@DEPTCODE INT,
@COA VARCHAR(50),
@MAP VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

BEGIN
SET @SQL = N'SELECT 
              A.GL_EXCEPT_ID AS ''GL ID''
            , A.COA_SYSTEM AS ''Account Type''
            , A.ENTN AS ''Entity''
            , A.MED_CTR AS ''Medical Center''
            , (''['' + A.LOCN + ''] '' + B.LOCN_DESC) AS ''Location Code''
            , (''['' + A.CTRN + ''] '' + C.CTRN_DESC) AS ''Cost Center''
            , (''['' + RTRIM(A.FUND) + ''] '' + A.FUND_DESC) AS ''Fund''
            , A.ROLLUP_TYPE_ID AS ''Rollup ID''
            , A.ROLLUP_TYPE_DESC AS ''Rollup Type''
            , A.MAPPING AS ''Mapping''
FROM V_ROLLUP_GL_DESC_REV1 A
    LEFT JOIN T_ROLLUP_GL_LOCN B
        ON A.LOCN = B.LOCN
            AND A.MED_CTR_ID = B.MED_CTR_ID
            AND A.COA_SYSTEM = B.COA_SYSTEM
    LEFT JOIN T_ROLLUP_GL_CTRN C
        ON A.CTRN = C.CTRN
            AND A.COA_SYSTEM = C.COA_SYSTEM
WHERE (A.DEPT_ID = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@DEPTCODE)+')
        AND A.COA_SYSTEM IN ('+@COA+')
        AND A.MAPPING IN ('+@MAP+''')'
PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)
END
END
```

Query

```
USE [Rollup2]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[USP_GET_GL_BY_DEPT]
    @DEPTCODE = 1000,
    @COA = N'''COA'',''COA_SYSTEM''',
    @MAP = N'''DEFAULT'',''EXCEPTION'''

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem is:

```
@MAP VARCHAR(10)
```

but you are passing in a value much longer:

```
@MAP = N'''DEFAULT'',''EXCEPTION'''
```

increase your length to:

```
@MAP VARCHAR(50)
```

Second problem is this line, there are too many single quotes:

```
AND A.MAPPING IN ('+@MAP+''')'
```

change it to:

```
AND A.MAPPING IN ('+@MAP+')'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I see the problem was the VARCHAR length.  Originally had the single quote and changed it due to the error.